# django select_related tree path

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a django model that represents edges of a tree and a model that represents the nodes:

```
class Edge(models.Model):
nodeFrom = models.ForeignKey('Node', related_name='+')
nodeTo = models.ForeignKey('Node', related_name='+')

class Node(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    parentNode = models.ForeignKey('Node', null=True)
```

Is there a way to build tree paths for a subtree with only one database hit?

I tried this:

```
userEdges = Edge.objects.filter(nodeFrom__in=userNodes, nodeTo__in=userNodes).select_related('nodeFrom', 'nodeTo)
```

but if I try to build the path like this,

```
def get_path(node, userEdges):
    path = [node]
    while path[-1].parentNode_id != None:   
        path.append(userEdges.get(nodeTo=node).nodeFrom)

    return path
```

a database access is always caused by that line:

```
userEdges.get(nodeTo=node).nodeFrom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your using `.get`. Since you've already retrieved the `userEdges` and have them in memory, you can do:

```
while ... :
    currentEdge = next(e for e in userEdges if e.nodeTo == node)
    path.append(currentEdge.nodeFrom)
```